# Fire event with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a button bar on a web page that allows me to navigate to a specific page if I click on the page button. I need to know if it's possible with python selenium to fire a event for a specific page. For instance, if I want to go directly to page '100', how can I fire this event with python selenium. Follows below examples of the page buttons.

```
<td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '1'});">1</td>
<td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '2'});">2</td>
<td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '3'});">3</td>
```

Comment: But you can click on the button via Selenium. Is it not a case?

Comment: The button for the page 100 is not showed on the first page. I have to move between pages until the the button for page 100 is showed.

Comment: Click on page 3 and then once the page loads, look at the URL. Does it contain page information? If so, you can just navigate to the desired URL and add the page #, e.g. `http://somesite.com/results?page=100`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try execute the code with `execute_script()`

```
# find element for argument "this"
thisEl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(@class, "rich-datascr-inact") and contains(text(), "100")]')
driver.execute_script('''
window.Event.fire(arguments[0], 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '100'})
''', thisEl)
```